# Feature conflict between jsp-2.2 and adminCenter-1.0

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-liberty

I have downloaded the latest stable WLP runtime with JAVA EE7 for solaris environment.

```
Version : 16.0.0.3
```

The zip file is extracted and profile is created. AdminCenter installed by using below command:

```
.\installUtility install adminCenter-1.0
```

**Server.xml file** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">

    <!-- Enable features -->
    <featureManager>
        <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
        <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>
    <quickStartSecurity userName="admin" userPassword="adminpwd" />

    <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="Liberty" />

    <featureManager>
        <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>
    <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="{xor}PjsyNjEfbm1s" />


    <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                  host="*"
                  httpPort="9060"
                  httpsPort="9443" />

    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

</server>
```

The WAS service also started. In Browser, after providing the credentials, it shows blank page. The log message is given below:

> [ERROR   ] CWWKF0033E: The singleton features servlet-3.0 and
>   servlet-3.1 cannot be loaded at the same time.  The configured
>   features adminCenter-1.0 and
>   com.ibm.websphere.appserver.restConnectorjaxrs-1.0 include one or more
>   features that cause the conflict. Your configuration is not supported;
>   update server.xml to remove incompatible features.
>
> [ERROR   ] CWWKF0033E: The singleton features
>   com.ibm.websphere.appserver.internal.jaxrs-1.1 and
>   com.ibm.websphere.appserver.internal.jaxrs-2.0 cannot be loaded at the
>   same time.  The configured features adminCenter-1.0 and
>   com.ibm.websphere.appserver.restConnectorjaxrs-1.0 include one or more
>   features that cause the conflict. Your configuration is not supported;
>   update server.xml to remove incompatible features.
>
> [ERROR   ] CWWKF0033E: The singleton features
>   com.ibm.websphere.appserver.javax.annotation-1.1 and
>   com.ibm.websphere.appserver.javax.annotation-1.2 cannot be loaded at
>   the same time.  The configured features jsp-2.2 and
>   com.ibm.websphere.appserver.restConnectorjaxrs-1.0 include one or more
>   features that cause the conflict. Your configuration is not supported;
>   update server.xml to remove incompatible features.
>
> [ERROR   ] CWWKF0033E: The singleton features
>   com.ibm.websphere.appserver.javaeeCompatible-6.0 and
>   com.ibm.websphere.appserver.javaeeCompatible-7.0 cannot be loaded at
>   the same time.  The configured features jsp-2.2 and
>   com.ibm.websphere.appserver.restConnectorjaxrs-1.0 include one or more
>   features that cause the conflict. Your configuration is not supported;
>   update server.xml to remove incompatible features.
>
> [AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. [ERROR   ]
>   CWWKE0702E: Could not resolve module: com.ibm.ws.jaxrs-2.0.common
>   [502]

But the service is up and running. Kindly help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3):

This error is caused by a rare scenario where the feature resolution of `installUtility` leaves the Liberty runtime feature resolution with an incompatible set of features.

**To resolve the issue:**

Remove the `jsp-2.2` feature from your server.xml.  The correct JSP feature will be pulled in automatically by `adminCenter-1.0`

**This error happened because...**

You have the following features configured in your server.xml:

- jsp-2.2
- adminCenter-1.0
- ssl-1.0

If you had every feature in Liberty installed, the runtime would be able to figure out the correct set of features.  However, the `installUtility` is not quite as smart as the Liberty runtime when it comes to feature resolution, which is why you've been stuck with this incompatible set of features in your install image, which has resulted in a feature conflict.

**Side note:**

It is best practice to only use a single `<featureManager>` element (per xml file).

Additionally, you have `<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore">` defined twice in your server.xml (the second one will be used).  This is likely a typo, but in any case the behavior is defined by [Liberty:Configuration element merging rules](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_confg_element_merging_rule.html)

Comment: I have included all the features and started the service. Now Im not getting any error. But after login to adminCenter, we are getting the blank page. How to fix it?

Comment: glad your issue is resolved.  The blank error page after adminCenter login could be caused by a lot of different things.  I would recommend posting a new question with all of the relevant details (configuration, error messages, procedure)