# adminCenter-1.0 and jaxrs-2.1

Tags: websphere-liberty

Running WebSphere Liberty 20.0.0.1

Enabling adminCenter on a liberty server running jaxrs I gethis message:

```
The configured features jaxrs-2.1 and adminCenter-1.0 include one or more features that cause the conflict.
```

So how can I run adminCenter together with other applications require some newer features ?

The complete feature set is :

```
<featureManager>
  <feature>jaxrs-2.1</feature> 
  <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>
```

/bwa

Comment: Can you share your full feature set (all the feature elements) in server.xml ?   It also could help to mention what method and/or artifact you're using to install Liberty from.

Comment: You also might get some insight if you can find a message like this in the messages.log:      com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load conflicting versions of features "com.ibm.websphere.appserver.javax.servlet-3.1" and "com.ibm.websphere.appserver.javax.servlet-4.0".  The feature dependency chains that led to the conflict are: com.ibm.websphere.appserver.cdi-1.2 -> ..... and com.ibm.websphere.appserver.batch-1.0 ->....

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41380887/feature-conflict-between-jsp-2-2-and-admincenter-1-0
although it's regarding a different feature, it will likely be the same configuration issue

Comment: The feature set is as simple as this :

Just try it someone ... U dont need any application to reproduce



<featureManager>
  <feature>jaxrs-2.1</feature> 
  <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>

Comment: OK, that clarifies the feature set.  What about the install?   Are you using Maven to install Liberty?  Which artifact?  Are you downloading a zip from another source?  Which zip?   The issue you're hitting might only surface from certain install paths but not others.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update to 20.0.0.2, it works fine on mine. Or try to clean restart on yours.

```
Launching defaultServer (WebSphere Application Server 20.0.0.2/wlp-1.0.37.cl200220200204-1746) on Eclipse OpenJ9 VM, version 11.0.6+10 (en_PL)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server defaultServer has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0100I: This product is licensed for development, and limited production use. The full license terms can be viewed here: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/license/base_ilan/ilan/20.0.0.2/lafiles/en.html
[INFO    ] CWWKE0002I: The kernel started after 0.858 seconds
[INFO    ] CWWKF0007I: Feature update started.
[WARNING ] CWWKS3103W: There are no users defined for the BasicRegistry configuration of ID com.ibm.ws.security.registry.basic.config[basic].
[INFO    ] CWWKS0007I: The security service is starting...
[INFO    ] OSGi Work Path [ D:\Liberty\wlp-javaee8-20.0.0.2\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\41\data ]
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications.
[INFO    ] Aries Blueprint packages not available. So namespaces will not be registered
[INFO    ] DYNA1001I: WebSphere Dynamic Cache instance named baseCache initialized successfully.
[INFO    ] DYNA1071I: The cache provider default is being used.
[INFO    ] DYNA1056I: Dynamic Cache (object cache) initialized successfully.
[AUDIT   ] CWPKI0820A: The default keystore has been created using the 'keystore_password' environment variable.
[INFO    ] CWWKS4105I: LTPA configuration is ready after 0.006 seconds.
[INFO    ] CWWKS0008I: The security service is ready.
[INFO    ] CWWKS1123I: The collective authentication plugin with class name NullCollectiveAuthenticationPlugin has been activated. 
[INFO    ] Successfully loaded default keystore: D:/Liberty/wlp-javaee8-20.0.0.2/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/resources/security/key.p12 of type: PKCS12
[INFO    ] CWWKX1015I: FILE persistence layer initialized for the Admin Center.
[INFO    ] CWWKX1063I: FILE persistence layer initialized for the Admin Center tool data loader.
[INFO    ] CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint has been started and is now listening for requests on host kubernetes.docker.internal  (IPv4: 127.0.0.1) port 9080.
[INFO    ] CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint-ssl has been started and is now listening for requests on host kubernetes.docker.internal  (IPv4: 127.0.0.1) port 9443.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [adminCenter-1.0, distributedMap-1.0, el-3.0, jaxrs-2.1, jaxrsClient-2.1, jndi-1.0, json-1.0, jsonp-1.1, jsp-2.3, localConnector-1.0, restConnector-2.0, servlet-4.0, ssl-1.0].
[INFO    ] CWWKF0008I: Feature update completed in 1.038 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The defaultServer server is ready to run a smarter planet. The defaultServer server started in 1.897 seconds.
[INFO    ] SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: IBMJMXConnectorREST.
[INFO    ] SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: The Liberty Server Config Tool.
[INFO    ] SRVE0250I: Web Module The Liberty Server Config Tool has been bound to default_host.
[INFO    ] SRVE0250I: Web Module IBMJMXConnectorREST has been bound to default_host.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9080/ibm/adminCenter/serverConfig-1.0/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9080/IBMJMXConnectorREST/
[INFO    ] CWWKX0103I: The JMX REST connector is running and is available at the following service URL: service:jmx:rest://localhost:9443/IBMJMXConnectorREST
[INFO    ] CWWKX0103I: The JMX REST connector is running and is available at the following service URL: service:jmx:rest://localhost:9443/IBMJMXConnectorREST
[INFO    ] SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: ibm/api.
[INFO    ] SRVE0250I: Web Module ibm/api has been bound to default_host.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9080/ibm/api/
[INFO    ] SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: The Liberty Explore Tool.
[INFO    ] SRVE0250I: Web Module The Liberty Explore Tool has been bound to default_host.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9080/ibm/adminCenter/explore-1.0/
[INFO    ] SESN8501I: The session manager did not find a persistent storage location; HttpSession objects will be stored in the local application server's memory.
[INFO    ] SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: The Liberty Admin Center.
[INFO    ] SRVE0250I: Web Module The Liberty Admin Center has been bound to default_host.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9080/adminCenter/
[INFO    ] SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/ibm/api
[INFO    ] SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/adminCenter
[INFO    ] SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/ibm/adminCenter/serverConfig-1.0
[INFO    ] SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/ibm/adminCenter/explore-1.0
[INFO    ] SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/IBMJMXConnectorREST
[INFO    ] SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[INFO    ] SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[INFO    ] SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[INFO    ] SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[INFO    ] SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[INFO    ] DYNA1056I: Dynamic Cache (object cache) initialized successfully.
[INFO    ] SRVE0242I: [com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.server.rest] [/IBMJMXConnectorREST] [JMXRESTProxyServlet]: Initialization successful.
[INFO    ] SRVE9103I: A configuration file for a web server plugin was automatically generated for this server at D:\Liberty\wlp-javaee8-20.0.0.2\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer\logs\state\plugin-cfg.xml.
[INFO    ] SRVE0242I: [com.ibm.ws.ui] [/adminCenter] [/login.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID admin. An invalid user ID or password was specified.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0016I: Starting server configuration update.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKG0017I: The server configuration was successfully updated in 0.030 seconds.
[INFO    ] SRVE0242I: [com.ibm.ws.ui] [/adminCenter] [/toolbox.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[INFO    ] SRVE0242I: [com.ibm.ws.rest.handler] [/ibm/api] [RESTProxyServlet]: Initialization successful.
[INFO    ] CWWKX1029I: The Admin Center default toolbox for user admin loaded.
[INFO    ] CWWKX1000I: The Admin Center default catalog loaded.
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be some strange issue with my install. After running a fresh binary and installUtility it works fine.